# Where can I find Jersey API jars?

Tags: java, jersey, jsr

I need to download the JSR 311 Java library (Jersey) jars. Java.net has the API for download but it is inexplicably down and can't seem to find it anywhere else. Can someone please help as I can not continue my current project without Jersey. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the JAR files at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec/1.0.1.Final/

In any case, use a dependency management system like Maven or Ivy to make things easier.

Comment: That's ... not jersey (though he should be using maven, yes).

Comment: That's JAX-RS API... JSR-311 is not Jersey.

Comment: Jersey is a JSR311 implementation, and the one that he is specifically asking for in his question.

Comment: Not exactly. He's asking for the API and not for the implementation.

Comment: You're right ... the part where he specifically says Jersey (twice) and mentions that java.net (where jersey lives) is down ... is obviously in my head ...

Comment: d'oh! apologies, misread.

Comment: No worries. And please ignore the sarcasm, it comes built in with my personality. :D

Answer (score 0):

As Alessandro notes in his answer, You really should be using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) at least for dependency management.

That being said, you can get the latest Jersey jars from the apache maven central repository even without using maven:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.jersey%7Cjersey-bundle%7C1.9%7Cjar